# What does this stamp on my teapot say?

Tags: character-identification

I'm not sure if the orientation is correct but I believe the bottom left symbol might be 制. This is as clear of a shot that I can get of the stamp. Please and thank you.

[image: Stamp photo]

Comment: I'm not sure if the orientation is correct, but please decipher the seal stamp symbols at the bottom of the teapot.
This is as clear of a shot that I can get of the stamp. Please and thank you. [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Kec7.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Kec7.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

the orientation is correct, read as “荊溪張製”, roughly, means “made by mr/ms 張 of county 荊溪”

have fun :)

Answer (score 0):

About 500 years ago, ceramics in 荊溪 County became famous. If your teapot is genuine, it should be worth a lot, at least several hundred dollars. 荊溪 is a county under the jurisdiction of Changzhou City, Jiangsu Province, where the ceramic products are very famous. Between 1970 and 1990, Jingxi County produced many ceramics. The maker stamped a mark on the bottom of the ceramic. This pot was made by a businessman surnamed 张.